# Getting coordinates by clicking over a circle overlay

Tags: google-maps-api-3, overlays

I have a script that gets the coordinate of a map by clicking. At the same time, there are circle overlays spread across the map. I can get the coordinate of anywhere but the area covered by the overlays. What is a good work-around for this problem?

Comment: Either make the circles with {clickable: false} or capture the click event on the circles also.

Comment: I used {clickable: false}. It appeared to be the easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make the circles with {clickable: false} or capture the click event on the circles also